# Why can't any rows query in SQLite Android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm having problem querying SQLite database in android. The way I do it is to use the `WHERE Profile ?` condition to let it be any value. but when i call `cursordel.getCount()` it returns 0, whereas in my `Profile` column there are many rows.

```
SQLiteDatabase DB1 = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues contentValues1 = new ContentValues();

Cursor cursordel = DB1.rawQuery("Select * from Userdetails WHERE Profile = ? ", null);
Log.i(TAG,"Count cursordel:" + String.valueOf(cursordel.getCount()));
```

[image]

**My question is, how using `WHERE Profile ?` can I count the number of rows in the database, so that I can then use `long result = DB1.update("Userdetails", contentValues, "FirstProfile =?", null);` to properly update the box `Profile ?`**

Comment: I found the solution by myself. fix `null` to `new String[] {FirstProfile}`.

Answer (score 0):

The placeholder `?` is used when you want to provide a parameter as the 2nd argument for `rawQuery()`, something like:

```
Cursor cursordel = DB1.rawQuery(
    "Select * from Userdetails WHERE Profile = ?", 
    new String[] {"{1ABC#428#240#12}"}
);
```

which will return the rows of the table where `Profile` is equal to `{1ABC#428#240#12}`.

If you want to get all the rows of the table you should remove the `WHERE` clause and pass `null` as the 2nd argument for `rawQuery()`:

```
Cursor cursordel = DB1.rawQuery("Select * from Userdetails", null);
```

Comment: I'm found the solution, thank you anyway.

Comment: @SaHiRo Fine if it is solved and don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark.